# SwiftUI ActionSheet position on iPad

Tags: ios, swiftui, actionsheet

When using SwiftUI's `ActionSheet` inside a `List` on iPad, it appears in a wrong position, especially if the style of the list is set to `GroupedListStyle`.

With this code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var presentAction: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {

                Section {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.presentAction.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("Present")
                    }
                    .actionSheet(isPresented: $presentAction) {
                        ActionSheet(title: Text("This is an action sheet"), buttons: [
                            .destructive(Text("Destroy all"))
                        ])
                    }
                }
            }.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}
```

The result is as in the following screen (iPad Pro 10.5"):

[image: sample app screen]

But in my current app, is even worse:

[image]

Comment: It look like some sort of anchor point issue? Look up anchor point..

Comment: You cannot set any anchor point in SwiftUI, it should be automatically detected bby the framework, AFAIK

Comment: Look here https://swiftwithmajid.com/2020/03/18/anchor-preferences-in-swiftui/

Comment: I think anchor preferences aren't related to this issue